# The :link pseudo-class does match visited links

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I was reading about CSS pseudo-classes and I came across the `:link` pseudo-class.

Everyone says that the `:link` pseudo-class matches link elements that have an "href" attribute **and** haven't been visited yet.

The first condition is true as I checked it out, but apparently the second condition (only matching unvisited links) is not the case (at least with Google Chrome) as you can see in the picture below:

[image: Google Chrome Dev Tools]

What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit confusing but if you refer to [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#link) you will find:

> UAs may therefore treat **all links as unvisited links**, or implement other measures **to preserve the user's privacy** while rendering visited and unvisited links differently.

This is what is happening here. The trick is to create some restrictions to avoid having a *big* difference between the styles of visited and unvisited links.

Technically, all the styles you will apply to `a:link` will also apply to `a:visited` unless you override them inside `a:visited` and you are limited to the styles that you can apply inside `:visited` so you cannot override everything:

> You can style visited links, but there are limits to which styles you can use. Only the following styles can be applied to visited links:
>
> - color
> - background-color
> - border-color (and its sub-properties)
> - column-rule-color
> - outline-color
> - The color parts of the fill and stroke attributes
>
> In addition, even for the above styles, you won't be able to change the transparency between unvisited and visited links, as you otherwise would be able to using rgba(), hsla(), or the transparent keyword. <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector#Limits_to_visited_link_styles)</sup>

Here is an example to illustrate:

```css
a:link {
  font-size:50px;
  border:2px solid red;
  color:black;
  padding:20px;
  box-shadow:5px 5px 0 blue;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:10px;
}
a:visited {
 color:red; /* this will work */
 border:5px dotted green; /* only the color will work */
 background:black; /* This will not work because we cannot change transparent to opaque value */
 
 /*All the below will not work*/
  padding:0;
  box-shadow:-5px -5px 0 purple;
  display:inline;
  margin:9584px;
  font-size:10px;
}
```

```html
<a href="www.something.comg">not visited</a>

<a href="#">visited</a>
```

We are only allowed to slightly change the behavior from vistied to unvisited. Basically, we are only allowed to changed some colors.

From this you can also conculde that `a:link` is almost<sup>1</sup> the same as `a`. The difference is that the first one will only target links with `href` specified

<sup>1</sup>: `a:link` or `:link` remain more specific than `a`

```css
:link {
 font-size:40px;
}
a {
 font-size:10px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">a link</a>
```

Answer (score -2):

The `:visited` psuedoselector can change many properties (e.g. `color`, `background-color`) but unfortunately `font-size` is not one of them. This is why it would not change your font-size even if you were setting it in your :visited code.

The reason for the restriction is for privacy reasons. You can see more about the restrictions to visited [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited)

Comment: I didn't change the font-size in the :visited selector.

Comment: @AmirHosseinAhmadi Yes I am aware of this but in your original example (before it was edited) you showed font-size as something you wanted to edit. I am not sure why this answer has been downvoted several times although I have pointed out the same privacy reasons that the subsequent answer has. If those who downvoted would like to say why they downvoted it would be most useful.