# Animate unvisited links only with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have links inside `<div>` buttons and I'm trying to animate them only if the link is un-visited.

What I've tried so far:

- place

  ```
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
  ```

  inside `.nav-links a:link` only.
- place

  ```
  animation-play-state: running;
  ```

  inside `a:link`, and

  ```
  animation-play-state: paused;
  ```

  inside the other classes.

But none of these seems to work as expected.

```css
.nav-links a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.45em 0.9em;
    margin: 1.3em 1em 2.4em;
    border-radius: 1.14em;
    border: 0.11em solid;
    transition: 0.3s;
    animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}
@keyframes pulse {
    0% { box-shadow:0 0 0 0 red }
    70% { box-shadow:0 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0) }
    100% { box-shadow:0 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0) }
}
/* not clicked yet */
.nav-links a:link {
    color: red;
    border-color: red;
    animation-play-state: running;
}
.nav-links a:link:hover {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    animation-play-state: running;
}
/* already clicked */
.nav-links a:visited {
    color: black;
    border-color: black;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
.nav-links a:visited:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
/* clicking the button */
.nav-links a:active {
    padding: 0.36em 0.72em;
    margin: 1.94em 1.18em;
    transition: 0.1s;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-links">
<div class="nav-previous"><a href="..." rel="prev">unvisited</a></div>
<div class="nav-next"><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58806301/animate-unvisited-links-only-with-css" rel="next">visited</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57839759/8620333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:visited` CSS selector can change only a very limited range of CSS properties, to prevent leaking users' history to the site.

So, **there's no way** to animate a visited link differently than an unvisited one.

You can't even use JavaScript, as browsers will lie to it, imitating that no links was visited on the site.

The properties you can change in `:visited`:

- `color`
- `background-color`
- `border-color`
- `outline-color`
- `column-rule-color`

Read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector)

Comment: Oh, so javascript has to be used instead?

Comment: @soundwave No, unfortunately there's **really no way**. Browsers will lie to JS, imitating that no links was visited on the site...

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say that there's *really no way*, because with JS you can save on localStorage all links clicked by the user (visited ones), then when creating those buttons you can check if it is already visited by reading from localStorage, then adding a class with or without the animation. But yes, not easy and not simple way

Comment: @CalvinNunes And how do you track external sites?

Comment: Is there always a way to do, but it depends on how OP is building his site/webapp... He can have an array of objects of all links that will be rendered as buttons/links, then a listener on each button that on click save on localStorage that this link is visited... but it is not the discussion here. Your answer tell it all for OP (I also gave you a +1 :))

Comment: @CalvinNunes Thanks for explanation, each post has two buttons, one to move to the next post, one to move to previous post.